# "Activity A implements X" for unsupported API levels

Tags: android

In an app I am writing, I want to support sharing through the **ShareActionProvider** class,  which is available for API levels >= 14.

However, I want to support all Android versions down to API level 9 (without supporting sharing).
I could write 2 apps with

a) API levels < 14

```
public class MyActiv extends Activity {}
```

b) API levels >=14

```
public class MyActiv extends Activity implements OnShareTargetSelectedListener {}
```

Is there a way to keep everything in a unique java file ?

I've looked into reflection and delegation but can't figure anything conclusive yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a several approaches... one thing you could do is check it the current version is 14, then create `OnShareTargetSelectedListener` :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=14){
        OnShareTargetSelectedListener listener=new OnShareTargetSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onShareTargetSelected(ShareActionProvider source,
                    Intent intent) {
                //...
                return false;
            }
        };
        provider.setOnShareTargetSelectedListener(listener);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ovidiu, this looks promising. I am going to try it and will let you know.